# How can i upload image using glide from url path

Tags: android, image, imageview, load

I want to use Glide to get an image of the image url, but I get an error
I do not know why.

i already check what can i do but i don't understand what is my problem in my source code

```
     public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {



    Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Product> productList;
    String intent_first;
    String intent_last;
    String intent_phnumber;
    String intent_addr;


    public ProductAdapter(ArrayList<Product> productList, Context c, String pre_first, String pre_last, String detail_addr, String phNumber){
        this.mContext = c;
        this.productList = productList;
        this.intent_first = pre_first;
        this.intent_last = pre_last;
        this.intent_addr = detail_addr;
        this.intent_phnumber = phNumber;



    }


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView proimage;
        TextView pro_name;
        TextView pro_cont;
        TextView pro_price;

        MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);

            proimage = view.findViewById(R.id.productimage);
            pro_name = view.findViewById(R.id.productname);
            pro_cont = view.findViewById(R.id.productcont);
            pro_price= view.findViewById(R.id.productprice);

        }

    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_product, parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        final MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;
        final int Position = position;

        Log.e("result",productList.get(position).productimage);

        Glide.with(mContext).load(productList.get(position).productimage).into(myViewHolder.proimage);
        myViewHolder.pro_name.setText(productList.get(position).productname);
        myViewHolder.pro_cont.setText(productList.get(position).productcont);
        myViewHolder.pro_price.setText(productList.get(position).productprice + "원");



        myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),myViewHolder.text1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),myViewHolder.etp_name.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String proname = (String) myViewHolder.pro_name.getText();
                String proprise = (String) myViewHolder.pro_price.getText();
                String procont = (String) myViewHolder.pro_cont.getText();



                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ProductOrderActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("proname", proname);
                intent.putExtra("proprise",proprise);
                intent.putExtra("procont", procont);
                intent.putExtra("first", intent_first);
                intent.putExtra("last", intent_last);
                intent.putExtra("ph", intent_phnumber);
                intent.putExtra("addr", intent_addr);





                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }

        });


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return productList.size();

    }
```

'productimage' saved path img url

**The error occured from this code**

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(productList.get(position).productimage).placeholder(R.drawable.hotel).into(myViewHolder.proimage);
```

i want to know what is the problem...

**This is my Error from console**

```
2019-06-10 18:23:20.901 21127-21127/com.example.blogapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-06-10 18:23:20.904 21127-21127/com.example.blogapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.blogapp, PID: 21127
    java.lang.NullPointerException: You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:31)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:684)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:716)
        at com.example.together.Adapter.ProductAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ProductAdapter.java:88)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1308)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:350)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
2019-06-10 18:23:20.904 21127-21127/com.example.blogapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2718)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1572)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Could you please show your ViewHolder class

Comment: Can you add your fragment

Comment: i already added sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error mentioned ,     java.lang.NullPointerException: You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).

Your fragment view is yet not attached , make sure you have initialised your adapter and attached it to recycler view inside the onViewCreated method of the fragment . With this , your activity would be null. OnViewCreated is called after onCreatedView of the fragment which make sure , you perform all the action on the fragment after your view is created .

And again , no need to pass the context to adapter , as it seeems to be in google bad practices . If you need the context in the adapter ,then you can use view.getcontext() method to get the context .

Comment: Thnak you so much sir !

Comment: Welcome , Happy to help . Try to follow google sample for best practices and you can also use codelab  (Recommended by google). Link : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/